# missing image in confluence 3.0.1

Tags: confluence

I am using confluence 3.0.1 and have the problem that some images are not shown after logout. I remember there being a fix but cannot find anything despite extensive google searches.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Christian

Comment: Could you give some more information which images are not shown? Are these attachments, are they stored at a page of a wiki space? If stored at a page, is that page secured in any way?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. My homepage: http://www.zoonosis.ac.uk:8080/display/~csetzkorn/Home does not show my picture. Still one can access it via the attachments: http://www.zoonosis.ac.uk:8080/pages/viewpageattachments.action?pageId=17 (me.jpg). Does this answer what you were asking for? Thanks.

Comment: So you have configured your personal space to show your picture `me.jpg` on the Home page by including the correct wiki syntax there? Could you add the part of the page that should show your image (by adding it to the question)?

Comment: I think it is the space logo. However, I am struggling a bit I cannot even see the 'Change Space Logo' option at the moment - even as administrator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not have an installation of Confluence 3.0.1 available, we use a more current version 3.4.9, but perhaps the things are similar.

I think the reason for your missing image is simple. Your profile image is stored in the people directory, and you don't have access to the people directory without login. So even if anonymous access is allowed in your personal wiki, the space logo is taken from the people directory, and there the anonymous user has no access.

There is no workaround known to that problem. Atlassian states that it is a feature, not a bug. See the issue https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONF-16626 for a similar case. In newer versions of confluence, a question mark is shown to indicate that a profile picture should exist, but is not shown. So it does not look anymore like a technical bug.

[image]